# GHC - turning iterate into a tight loop

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to learn/evaluate Haskell and I'm struggling with getting efficient executable for a simple case.
The test I'm using is a PRNG sequence (replicating PCG32 RNG). I've written it as an iteration of a basic state transition function (I'm looking only at the state for now).

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Bits
import Data.Word

iterate' f !x = x : iterate' f (f x)

main = print $ pcg32_rng 100000000

pcg32_random_r :: Word64 -> Word64 -> Word64
pcg32_random_r !i !state = state * (6364136223846793005 :: Word64) + (i .|. 1)
{-# INLINE pcg32_random_r #-}

pcg32_rng_s = iterate' (pcg32_random_r 1) 0

pcg32_rng n = pcg32_rng_s !! (n - 1)
```

I can get that code to compile and run. It still uses a lot more memory than it should and runs 10x slower than the C equivalent. The main issue seems to be that the iteration is not turned into a simple loop.

What am I missing to get GHC to produce faster / more efficient code here?

**EDIT**

This is the C version I compare against which captures in essence what I'm trying to achieve. I try for a fair comparison but let me know if I missed something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  uint64_t oldstate,state;
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<100000000;i++) {
    oldstate = state;
    // Advance internal state
    state = oldstate * 6364136223846793005ULL + (1|1);
  }
  printf("%ld\n",state);
}
```

I tried initally with the Prelude `iterate` function but this result in lazy evaluation and a stack overflow. The ìterate'`is aimed at fixing that issue.

My next step was to try to get GHC to inline `pcg32_random_r`and that's where I added the strictness to it but that doesn't seem to be enough. When I look at the GHC core, it is not inlined.

@WillemVanOnsem I confirm with `perform`the result is on par with C and actually the `pcg32_random_r`function was inlined. I'm reaching the limit of my grasp of Haskell and GHC at this stage. Can you elaborate on why `perform` performs better and how to decide when to use what?

Would this transformation be feasible automatically by the compiler or is it something that requires a design decision?

The reason to ask the last question is that I would like as much to separate functionality and implementation choice (speed / space tradeoffs, ...) to maximize reuse and I was hoping Haskell to help me there.

Comment: Can you show the C equivalent? Does it also allocate list elements one by one, or does it pre-allocate them all as an array?

Comment: Did you profile and determine that `Data.List.iterate` is slower than what you've written here? I think the strictness of `pcg32_random_r` is enough to avoid accumulating thunks and the Prelude version of `iterate` uses foldr/build fusion which may be optimized better by GHC

Comment: @cdk the problem with `iterate` is that the strictness of the function passed to it is irrelevant. It always builds up thunks if you discard elements of the result unevaluated.  That limits its suitability to cases where you evaluate most elements of the portion of its result that you consider.

Comment: @Carl user luqui once showed on SO how to overcome this by writing a map as a fold, using the seq to tie the mapping with the (:) node creation, so that access itself automatically forces the evaluation progressively. What's left is to write iterate as a map, `iter f x = ys where ys = {- x : map f ys = -} x : foldr ((:) . (f $!)) undefined ys`. Seem to work, when tested with `xs = iter (1:) [0 :: Int]` and then `head (xs !! 3)` and then `:sprint xs`.

Comment: @WillNess Sure, you can write a different function that is stricter than `iterate`. But there's nothing you can pass to `iterate` that prevents it from building up thunks if you discard some sequence values it produces.

Comment: @Carl I tested it, and with my `iter` function it was only 1.5x faster than with `iterate`, but when using OP's `iterate'` it was 17 times faster!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me that the issue is more that you **produce a list**, and **obtain the *i*-th element** from that list. As a result you are going to unfold that list function, and each time you construct a new element if you need to move further in the list.

Instead of constructing such list (which will construct new nodes, and perform memory allocations, and consume a lot of memory). You can construct a function that will perform a given function `n` times:

```
perform_n :: (a -> a) -> Int -> a -> a
perform_n !f = step
    where step !n !x | n <= 0 = x
                     | otherwise = step (n-1) (f x)
```

So now we can perform a function `f` `n` times. We can thus rewrite it like:

```
pcg32_rng n = perform_n (pcg32_random_r 1) (n-1) 0
```

If I compile this with `ghc -O2 file.hs` (GHC 8.0.2) run this file with `time`, I get:

```
$ time ./file
2264354473547460187
0.14user 0.00system 0:00.14elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3408maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+161minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

the original file produces the following benchmarks:

```
$ time ./file2
2264354473547460187
0.54user 0.00system 0:00.55elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3912maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+287minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

**EDIT**:

As [@WillNess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450569/ghc-turning-iterate-into-a-tight-loop/46451655#comment79860979_46451655) says, if you do not name the list, at runtime the list will be garbage collected: if you process through a list, and do not keep a reference to the head of the list, then that head can be removed once we step over it.

If we however construct a file like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Bits
import Data.Word

iterate' f !x = x : iterate' f (f x)

main = print $ pcg32_rng 100000000

pcg32_random_r :: Word64 -> Word64 -> Word64
pcg32_random_r !i !state = state * (6364136223846793005 :: Word64) + (i .|. 1)
{-# INLINE pcg32_random_r #-}

pcg32_rng n = iterate' (pcg32_random_r 1) 0 !! (n - 1)
```

we obtain:

```
$ time ./speedtest3
2264354473547460187
0.54user 0.01system 0:00.56elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3908maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+291minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

although the memory burden can be reduced, there is little impact on time. The reason is probably that working with list elements creates *cons* objects. So we do a lot of packing and unpacking into lists. This also results in constructing a lot of objects (and memory allocations) which still produces overhead.

Comment: This compares favorably with a straightforward C solution (i.e., `state = state * ... + (i | 1)` in a loop, and compiled with `gcc -O2`) -- both run in about 120 milliseconds on my laptop -- so this is probably about the best achievable performance.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr: well of course it is possible to probably find a few additional optimizations, but I guess the most important bottleneck is probably fixed :).

Comment: a tentative  rule of thumb is [*"if you name it, it will stay"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3c_pJ_CLJQ) (in memory that is). So maybe something as simple as writing `pcg32_rng n = iterate' (pcg32_random_r 1) 0 !! (n - 1)` (and of course *not* defining `pcg32_rng_s`) would have the same effect? Would it interest you to test this hypothesis?

Comment: @WillNess: it is `0.54s`. This is logical: if you "unfold" this list construction function, you will keep constructing list nodes. Which is where the time overhead comes from. The memory burden will be less. But packing and unpacking in list nodes is probably the reason of the time overhead.

Comment: so it didn't work. huh. the cons cells creation and destruction could conceivably be avoided altogether by the compiler, in such a clear case.

Comment: interesting whether it'll be faster with `pcg32_rng :: Int -> Word64` implemented directly as a recursive function, instead of using the general `perform_n`.